# NoMethodError when using .where (eager fetching)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have the following model classes...

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title
  has_many :imageTags
  has_many :tags, :through => :imageTags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :imageTags
  has_many :images, :through => :imageTags
end

class ImageTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :position
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

And when I use `find` for getting the Tag with the id 1

```
t = Tag.find(1);
@images = t.images;
```

But when I do the same with `where`, I get a `NoMethodError`, with the description `undefined method 'images'`:

```
t = Tag.where(:name => "foo");
@images = t.images;
```

I also tried adding `.includes(:images)` before the `.where` statement, but that doesn't work too. **So, how can I get all `Images` that belong to a `Tag`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.where` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation instance, not a single object. Tack on a `.first` to grab (presumably) the only record returned:

```
t = Tag.where(name: "foo").first
@images = t.images
```